# Add values indirect to nested struct

Tags: go, struct

i setup a nested struct in Golang and i want to fill it with values indirect.

```
type Categories struct {
    A ABCDE `json:"A"`
    B ABCDE `json:"B"`
    C ABCDE `json:"C"`
    D ABCDE `json:"D"`
    E ABCDE `json:"E"`
}

type ABCDE struct {
    Foo string `json:"foo`
}
```

Direct is working of course:

```
categories:= Categories{}
Categories.A.Foo = "Salute"
```

Indirect as pseudo code:

```
categories:= Categories{}
Categories.["A"].Foo = "Salute"
```

Direct solution is of course no problem. Is there a way to implement the indirect solution, that i am able to put the nested object inside as parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection ([reflect package](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect)).

```
categories:= Categories{}
reflect.ValueOf(&categories).
    Elem().
    FieldByName("A").
    FieldByName("Foo").SetString("Salute")
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://play.golang.org/p/AC9mg_1hOCL)</kbd>